# cups won't install

Tags: ubuntu, cups

I had to remove cups from my machine to do some tests. I juste removed it with apt-get purge cups but now I can't install it again, so I can't print.
I have never seen such an error, can someone give me some explanations about what's happening ? (I mostly want to learn and understand my error, but I googled it up and there is so much different case. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04).

When I try to install it with apt-get install cups, I get this outcome :

```
root@pc-desktop:/home/pc# apt-get install cups
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
cups is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up cups (1.4.3-1ubuntu1.5) ...
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/cups missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
/usr/sbin/cupsd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/cupsd: undefined symbol: _httpReadGNUTLS
cups: unable to start scheduler.
invoke-rc.d: initscript cups, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing cups (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ghostscript-cups:
ghostscript-cups depends on cups; however:
Package cups is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ghostscript-cups (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-driver-gutenprint:
cups-driver-gutenprint depends on cups (>= 1.3.0); however:
Package cups is not configured yet.
cups-driver-gutenprint depends on ghostscript-cups; however:
Package ghostscript-cups is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing cups-driver-gutenprint (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
cups
ghostscript-cups
cups-driver-gutenprint
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And I have a prompt again.

Does somebody have any clue ? I really don't know where I should begin to search.
Thank you very much in advance.
Patrick.

Comment: what happens after an `apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: Well, nothing special unfortunately. I did remove cups, and tried with the force option but no, it won't instal...
http://pastebin.com/pjJazH45

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reinstalling Ubuntu did it. A bit rough.

Comment: "To fix a problem with my car's engine I bought a new car"

Answer (score 1):

hmmm try an autoremove after the install:

```
sudo apt-get purge cups && sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cups
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your hint, I thought it will work, but no :-(
I rebooted my system, but no it won't even open the Printing tool in System => Administration. It just does nothing, and there is still no way to print...
http://pastebin.com/Yh0Nijje

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
apt-get install --reinstall cups
```

Comment: I have the same kind of error.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZWscAxM4
Here is the outcome with the --reinstall flag.
I have tried it already. And I reaally don't know what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

If your CUPS is still installed, it sounds like your initscript is borked. Did you manually modify your CUPS startup script or the LSB headers?

Comment: Hello.
Yes I have uninstalled the 1.4.4 version and installed a previous version (1.3.8) for testing purpose. Now I have removed the 1.3.8 one and want to install the 1.4.4 back, but no it won't. I should have used a testing environnement. :-(

Comment: But have you modified your LSB headers? The only time I've ever run into this problem is when somebody got creative with the LSB headers because he wanted to add new functionality to the 'service' command.

Comment: Nope, I haven't touched the LSB headers. I don't even know what those are. I'm going to google it. The less I play with my working desktop machine, the better it will be. I can't print now because of an error I don't understand, and I'd rather fix it than doing a new and clean install. Thanks for helping me out, Adrian.